# SQL SELECT statement MAX date and table joins

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

In MySQL, I have a two tables as below :

```
         ClientTable               
    clientID    clientName            
    1           Client A              
    2           Client B             
    3           Client C             
    4           Client D             
    5           Client E              
    6           Client F              



                 NotesTable
    noteID  clientID    note    noteDate
    1           3       Test 1    12-Jun-14
    2           3       Test 2    18-Aug-14
    3           4       Test 3    23-Oct-14
    4           6       Test 4    25-May-14
    5           3       Test 5    25-Nov-14
    6           6       Test 6    16-Jul-14
```

I want to select **all** the clients from the client table and, where a note exists for the client, the date of the **latest** note entry. If no note exists for a client, then return null for the noteDate. Desired result set as follows :

```
    client ID   clientName  latestNoteDate  
    1           Client A    null    
    2           Client B    null    
    3           Client C    25-Nov-14   
    4           Client D    23-Oct-14   
    5           Client E    null    
    6           Client F    16-Jul-14
```

Any help appreciated, I have tried a few options using nested Select with MAX(noteDate) and various left joins but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why all the subqueries?

```
select ct.clientID, ct.clientName,max(nt.noteDate) latestNoteDate
from ClientTable  ct
left outer join NotesTable nt
on ct.clientID = nt.clientID 
group by ct.clientID, ct.clientName
```

Comment: I prefer this to my answer, which I'll leave because it does provide another example.

Comment: I do prefer this as well.  No need for a subquery unless the `noteId` is the max record.  In that case, you would need the subquery (with another join).  But nonetheless, as written, this is the preferable solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions, I have gone with the one presented above and it works perfectly for my application. Much appreciated!

Comment: Slight update, I realised that I needed to add a WHERE clause to filter out some of the notes returned from the notes table. Hence reverted to use a subquery (as per sgeddes response below). However then realised that MySQL doesnt allow subqueries when building a view and so split up the view into two. Works like a charm, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `outer join` with a subquery:

```
select c.clientid, c.clientname, n.latestnotedate
from client c
   left join (
       select clientId, max(noteDate) latestnotedate
       from notes
       group by clientId
   ) n on c.clientId = n.clientId
```

This assumes the `max(noteDate)` is the **latest** note entry.  If that's not the case, easy enough to use the `noteid` instead and then just include one additional join.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good place for using a sub-query. Try something like:

```
select c.id, c.name, n.latestNoteDate from client c
left join
(select clientid, MAX(notedate) as latestNoteDate from note
group by clientid) as n on n.clientid = c.id
```

The key is, find the data you want from the notes table first, then use that to join with the client data later.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, which uses a correlated sub-query.

```
SELECT ct.clientID,
       ct.clientName,
       (SELECT MAX(noteDate)
        FROM   notesTable nt
        WHERE  nt.clientID = ct.clientId)
FROM   clientTable ct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select clienttable.clientID, clienttable.clientName, notes.noteDate
left outer join NotesTable notes on notes.clientID = clienttable.clientID and noteDate = (select      max(noteDate) from NotesTable where notes.clientID = clienttable.clientID)
```

It will return null if there are no note entries.

OR

```
select clienttable, clientID, clienttable.clientName, (select max(noteDate) from NotesTable where notes.clientID = clienttable.clientID) noteDate
```